# Run sql file in database from terminal

Tags: mysql, database, shell, terminal

I have a server and within that server I have an sql script in the /var/www/ directory. That script is to create tables and databases. I need to know how to execute this sql script from terminal or some client while keeping the file on the server.

PS- I don't know much of the terminology for this topic so I will look into other suggestions for my approach.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I presume that it is MYSQL. To run it from Unix / Linux environment you must do this:

```
$ mysql -h "server-name" -u "your_username" -p "your_password" "database-name" < "filename.sql"
```

There is another way:

```
mysql --host=localhost --user=your_username --password=your_password  -e "filename.sql"
```

Comment: What if my sql script needs to create a database? How, then, would I have a database name to use for that command line?

Comment: Try this:    mysql -uyour_username -pyour_password < filename.sql

Comment: Second way does not work for me, the argument to `-e` is a valid SQL statement, not a path. E.g.: `mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306 --user=root --password=your_password -e "select 1;"`

Comment: My MySQL doesn't respond to `$ mysql -h "server-name" -u "your_username" -p "your_password" "database-name" < "filename.sql"`, do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Tomislav I agree with your answer but writing password in the command line together is a bad idea. If you leave just -p and not writing the password then the system will ask you to enter the password.

Comment: @XPMai Can you please write your error so I can help you out? Usually, it doesn't give any output if you run this query. But please check my answer if you are using a newer version.

Answer (score 41):

Try this:

```
mysql -u your_username -p your_password

use db_name

source <path_to_sql_file>/file.sql
```

Comment: I selected a databse before "source" command: " use <databe_name>". And then "source <path_to_sql_file>/file.sql"

Answer (score 7):

If you want to run an SQL file for a specific database, then select the database first:

```
mysql -u your_username -p your_password

use db_name

source <path_to_sql_file>/file.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

The above answer of @Tomislav is correct but I do not like to write the password with the command-line option.

1. If you did not create the new database and want to create it with a .SQL file then use the below statement.

   mysql -h {YOUR_HOST} -u {USERNAME} -p < {FILENAME.sql}

then MySQL CLI will ask for the password (The best way to prevent the password from anyone). Write your password and hit Enter

2. If you have already created a database then use the below command.

   mysql -h {YOUR_HOST} -u {USERNAME} -p {DATABASE_NAME} < {FILENAME.sql}

then MySQL CLI will ask for the password. Write your password and hit Enter

Usually, the .SQL file doesn't have any print statements. So you have to enter and check with your MySQL CLI.